# How to remove the side padding from the Graphical Style DatePicker in SwiftUI?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

As you can see from the screenshot below, the `GraphicalDatePickerStyle` date picker by default comes with a side padding on both sides. How to remove the side padding so that the control can align with other controls on the top and bottom.

Add a padding 0 modifier does not change anything. One workaround would be to add some offset to the control but we just want to be certain there is no better choice.

```
DatePicker("", selection: $actionNotificationTime, displayedComponents: .hourAndMinute)
  .padding(0)
```

[image]

The same picker inside Settings is perfectly aligned

[image]

Comment: Can you please let me know how to change AM and PM selection colour

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The workaround with space offset on the control. Not sure if it would be "perfect" in all screen sizes but at least it is close enough.

```
DatePicker("", selection: $actionNotificationTime, displayedComponents: .hourAndMinute)
    .offset(x: 10)
```

[image]

Comment: Applying `.offset(x: 10)` will move the component but not shrink it. It might be better to use `.padding(.trailing, -10)` instead (although in this case it doesn't rally matter).

Comment: Use the following `.labelsHidden()`